# String split issue in R preprocessing data for GCalignR

Tags: r, split, preprocessor, text-to-column

Trying to take multiple .txt (GC-FID) files, pull out two columns of data and assign them to an object I can eventually pass to GCalignR. Is there a better way to process this data for GCalignR?

Auxiliary functions causing issue:

'''

```
# nonempty strings after splitting a row by one space
get_nonempty_splits = function(row) {
  s = strsplit(row, "[[:space:]]")
  s = s[[1]]
  l = c()
  for (i in 1:length(s)) {
    if (s[i] != "") {
      l = c(l, s[i])
    }
  }
  return(l)
}

# filenames have .txt, names do not
filenames_to_names = function(x) {
  l = c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x1 = strsplit(x, "[.]")[[i]][1]
    l = c(l, x1)
  }
  return(l)
}

# get data row indices
get_data_row_inds = function(df) {
  ind_start = 0
  ind_end = 0
  for (i in 1:length(df)) {
    row = df[i]
    # find start
    if (grepl("----", row)) {
      stopifnot(ind_start == 0)  # assert ind_start not set
      ind_start = i+1
    }
    # find end
    if (i == length(df) && ind_end == 0) {
      ind_end = length(df)
    } else if (grepl("Totals", row) && grepl(":", row)) {
      stopifnot(ind_end == 0)  # assert ind_end not set
      ind_end = i-1
    }
  }
  stopifnot(ind_start != 0)
  stopifnot(ind_end != 0)
  return(ind_start:ind_end)
}
```

'''

'''

```
path_to_raw_data = "/Users/input"
path_to_processed_data = "."
# get paths for all .txt files in pathToRawData directory
paths = list.files(path_to_raw_data, full.name=TRUE, pattern = ".txt")
filenames = list.files(path_to_raw_data, full.name=FALSE, pattern = ".txt")
names = filenames_to_names(filenames)  # without .txt extension

# get data from text file
processed_data = list()
df_lengths = c()
for (i in 1:length(paths)) {  # i indexes the raw files
  path = paths[i]
  df = read.delim(path, fileEncoding= 'UTF-16LE', header=TRUE)
  df = df[[1]]
  inds = get_data_row_inds(df)
  df_lengths = c(df_lengths, length(inds))
  times = c()
  areas = c()
  for (j in inds) {  # j indexes the data rows of a raw file
    row = df[j]
    row = get_nonempty_splits(row)
    time = row_to_time(row)
    area = row_to_area(row)
    times = c(times, time)
    areas = c(areas, area)
  }
  pairs = data.frame(time = times, area = areas)
  processed_data[[i]] = pairs
}
```

'''

Getting this error: Error in strsplit(row, "[[:space:]]") : non-character argument

Any advice how to solve this? Is it the file encoding? Processed-data =list() returns nothing...?

header of input:
'''

> dput(head(df))
> structure(c(59L, 53L, 45L, 48L, 47L, 52L), .Label = c("                                                Inj Volume : 1 µl",
> "                          *** End of Report ***", "                         Area Percent Report                         ",
> "   1   1.353  1  BB        2.85703 2.453e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "   2   1.952  1  BV     4411.39551  0.03787 ?                                                 ",
> "   3   2.058  1  VV     4693.20215  0.04029 ?                                                 ",
> "   4   2.089  1  VV     6614.89502  0.05679 ?                                                 ",
> "   5   2.139  2            0.00000  0.00000 NG                                                ",
> "   6   2.452  2            0.00000  0.00000 1, 3-DNB                                          ",
> "   7   3.149  2            0.00000  0.00000 2, 4-DNT                                          ",
> "   8   3.315  1  VV S   1.15784e7  99.39858 ?                                                 ",
> "   9   3.347  1  VV S   5169.44629  0.04438 ?                                                 ",
> "  #   [min]                            %", "  10   3.372  1  VV S   2.09449e4   0.17981 ?                                                 ",
> "  11   3.466  1  VV S   2535.17432  0.02176 ?                                                 ",
> "  12   3.547  1  VB S   2.45685e4   0.21092 ?                                                 ",
> "  13   3.602  1  BV T    451.00174  0.00387 ?                                                 ",
> "  14   3.686  1  VV T     40.45324  0.00035 ?                                                 ",
> "  15   3.734  1  VV T     13.40936  0.00012 ?                                                 ",
> "  16   3.819  1  VB T    508.57788  0.00437 ?                                                 ",
> "  17   4.119  1  BB       13.01144  0.00011 ?                                                 ",
> "  18   4.856  2            0.00000  0.00000 TNT                                               ",
> "  19   4.975  2            0.00000  0.00000 TNB                                               ",
> "  20   5.549  2            0.00000  0.00000 4-Am-DNT                                          ",
> "  21   5.869  2            0.00000  0.00000 RDX                                               ",
> "  22   5.943  2            0.00000  0.00000 2-Am-DNT                                          ",
> "  23   6.516  2            0.00000  0.00000 Tetryl                                            ",
> "  24  11.716  1  BB        1.75858 1.510e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  25  14.243  1  BB        2.55644 2.195e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  26  16.654  1  BB        3.81723 3.277e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  27  18.826  1  BB        2.58369 2.218e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  28  20.800  1  BB        1.51171 1.298e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  29  24.159  1  BB        1.78975 1.536e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  30  24.269  1  BB        1.81180 1.555e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  31  25.053  1  BB        2.96617 2.546e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  32  25.658  1  BB        6.15337 5.283e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  33  25.809  1  BB        3.89435 3.343e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  34  26.577  1  BB        4.02199 3.453e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  35  26.885  1  BB        2.48416 2.133e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  36  27.219  1  BB       14.88012  0.00013 ?                                                 ",
> "  37  27.465  1  BB        3.59732 3.088e-5 ?                                                 ",
> "  38  29.377  1  BB       18.55422  0.00016 ?                                                 ",
> "  39  32.554  1  BB       17.15620  0.00015 ?                                                 ",
> "----|-------|---|------|----------|--------|-------------------------",
> "=====================================================================",
> "2 Warnings or Errors :", "Acq. Instrument : Instrument 1                    Location : Vial 11",
> "Acq. Operator   : HHV                            Seq. Line :   2",
> "Calib. Data Modified  :      Tuesday, March 12, 2019 6:13:25 PM",
> "Dilution              :      1.0000", "Do not use Multiplier & Dilution Factor with ISTDs",
> "Injection Date  : 24-Feb-20, 14:37:34                  Inj :   1",
> "Instrument 1 2/24/2020 3:13:35 PM HHV", "Last changed    : 2/6/2020 12:59:45 PM by HHV",
> "Method          : C:\Chem32\1\DATA\IPOULIN\VOC_TEST_1 2020-02-24 13-49-15\VOC_TEST_HV.M",
> "Method Info     : VOC", "Multiplier            :      1.0000",
> "Peak RetTime Sig  Type     Area      Area    Name", "Sample Name: P1U1 hex 022420",
> "Sequence File   : C:\Chem32\1\DATA\IPOULIN\VOC_TEST_1 2020-02-24 13-49-15\VOC_TEST_1.S",
> "Signal 1: FID1 B, ", "Sorted By             :      Retention Time",
> "Totals :                1.16485e7 ", "Warning : Calibrated compound(s) not found",
> "Warning : Calibration warnings (see calibration table listing)"
> ), class = "factor")
> '''

Comment: It's hard to help when we don't know what your data looks like. please edit the main body of your question to include the output of ``dput(head(df))`` and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question.

I also can't tell where you are calling strsplit - is it within some user-defined function?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @fppatho please post the output of `dput(head(df))` of your read in file, this is more useful than the raw data

Comment: added requested output of put(head(df)) @starja

Answer (score 0):

Solved with adding: df = read.delim(path, fileEncoding= 'UTF-16LE', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE). The "stringsAsFactors = FALSE" being the solution. Thank you.